# Open Facebook Login On the same page instead of the popup

Tags: javascript, facebook-login

I would like to have facebook login page appears on the same tab as the website is on. The question is how could I modify the script below so that it won't be opened a new window, Thanks!

```
window.open("`https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" +
    e.data("appid") + 
    "&redirect_uri=" + 
    window.location.href + 
    "&scope=email,public_profile", "", null`))
```

Comment: by not using `window.open()`.

Comment: Any detail on how to get that around, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just use `window.location.href` instead of `window.open`.

```
window.location.href = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" + e.data("appid") + "&redirect_uri=" + window.location.href + "&scope=email, public_profile";
```

Comment: I have try to replace that part to the script and got some syntax error, really appreciate that you're helping me out, below is the full scrip, hopefully you could point me into the right direction.

Comment: http://cloudcongo.top//02402052FFAWE3E4QEDA43423525624253262135634363747/CONGOCLOUDTUTRUYTIRYRRYURETURU7757457H/wp-content/plugins/login-with-social/public/source/js/script.js

Comment: I have try multiple times, but still got nothing, thanks Arun, I'll keep trying.

Comment: You can use window.location.replace('url') also.